# How to find the roots of $-x^3+3x^2-7x+5 = 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

I would like to understand how to go about solving something like this, not just get the solution but some kind of methodology (that hopefully makes as much intuitive sense as possible); I honestly don't even know where to start.

$-x^3+3x^2-7x+5 = 0$

Comment: Do you know about the rational roots theorem? Alternatively, what do you get if you sum the coefficients?

Comment: @T.Bongers I don't know about that theorem unfortunately; the sum of the coefficients is -5, can we do something with 5 and -5? EDIT: sorry guess the sum of coefficients is 0, I wasn't counting 5 as one (shows you just how much I know!)

Comment: Try this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [Rational Root Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), the only possible rational roots are $x = \pm 1$ and $x = \pm 5$.

Now, which of these (if any) are in fact roots? (Hint: one of them is a root).

After you find one root $x = r$, you can factor the polynomial into $(x-r)$ times a quadratic, which you have a formula to solve.

Comment: The idea is that if we can find one root of a cubic, then we can reduce it to a quadratic. In this case, trying rational roots first does give us a rational root within at most 4 guesses. Of course, there is no guarantee that the cubic will have a rational root, but it is a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you for explaining what you did.

Comment: Actually, that comment was a response to someone else's comment, which was since deleted. The comment said something like "Who said anything about rational roots?"

Answer (score 2):

By inspection, $x = 1$ is a root. Thus, for $x \neq 1$,
$$
0 = -x^3 + 3x^2 - 7x + 5 = -x^3 + 3x^2 - 3x + 1 - (4x - 4) = -(x - 1)^3 -4(x - 1) 
$$
That is,
$$
(x-1)[-4 - (x - 1)^2] = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad (x - 1)^2 = -4 \quad x = 1\pm 2i
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Since the sum of the coefficients is $0$, one of the roots is $1$. The other roots can be found by dividing $-x^3+3x^2-7x+5$ by $x-1.$

Comment: Thanks, but do you have an explanation as to why you divide by $x-1$ to find the other roots and also why the fact that the coefficients add up to 0 means that one of the roots is 1?

Comment: If the sum of the coefficients is 0, then $1$ satisfies the equation $$a_n x^n+...+a_0 =0$$clearly.(set x=1 and use the assumption that the sum of the coefficients is 0.). But when 1 is the root of the equation, then it can be rewritten as $(x-1)q(x)$. Therefore the roots of the q(x) are the roots of the original equation as well. So we should the quotient q(x)...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

$$-x^3+3x^2-7x+5 = 0$$
By inspection $x=1$ is a root then divide by $x-1$ to find other two roots

Answer (score 1):

If you submit x=1 in the polynomial, you get 0. So that makes x=1 as one of the roots. We need to find 2 other, because it is a polynomial of degree 3. So we divide the polynomial by x-1, by polynomial long divison method.The polynomial then breaks into below form..

$${(x-1)(-x^2-4x+5)}=0$$

Or,$$(1-x)(x+5)(x-1)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT :** By Remainder theorem, we observe that $x-1$ is factor of the polynomial you have given. So It will be very easy to proceed, divide polynomial by x-1 by Horner's formula, you will get a quadratic polynomial, and then factorise quadratic polynomial if It is reducible over Z$[x]$.